# Unable to pin jar or packaged exe to taskbar

Tags: java, jar, installation

When using a plain JAR, or using Launch4J, I am unable to pin the app to the task bar.

How would I accomplish this? Are there any installers or jar packaging programs that allow for this functionality? I have been unable to find java installers that seemed to over the functionality.

Comment: avoid saying "any installers" as it tends to attract down-votes.

Comment: Where would you suggest I ask this question instead? It has a close suggestion for being not about programming... It's a straightforward and programming-related question.